# Communicating with a Silverlight 4 LocalMessageReceiver from a Desktop Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I am working on a little Helper Application for a Silverlight 4 OOB App that can be installed to enhance the capabilities of the SL a bit (improved Clipboard Support, Global Hotkeys etc).

I know that Silverlight's Local Message API is based on ALPC which is a rather undocumented Windows API but still, is there a way to talk to the LocalMessageReceiver from a non-silverlight application that I might have overlooked?

Otherwise I might need to stick to Plan B: a listening socket in the Helper App that the SL app connects to (SL app runs on elevated trust).

Comment: Since your app is trusted I would go with COM for communication with your helper app. Should be easier to use than sockets. Hacking Local Message API sounds pretty hard, but if you go down that way keep us updated. I'd be curious to learn more about it. If you can wait SL5 with P/Invoke could solve some of your problems without need for external helper app.

Comment: @Denis: Well the app is supposed to also work on OSX and that means no P/Invoke for me :)